# Line disappearing when pen thickness is very small

Tags: c#, wpf, geometry, line, frameworkelement

I'm developing an application that draws geometry elements like lines, etc. on a FrameworkElement. The lines, etc. are implemented as GeometryDrawing. As I want to preserve the line thickness at any (possible) zoom level, there is a routine that adapts the line thickness to the current zoom level and the size of the visible geometry.

Now I encounter a problem: At high zoom factors (like 490) - and thus resulting very low pen thicknesses like 0.010 - horizontal and vertical lines disappear. All other lines are not affected.

I already tried to set the SnapsToDevicePixels property of the FrameworkElement I'm drawing on to true but with no effect.

Comment: Pixel is the smallest unit. `0.01` in device-independent-units with default 96 DPI is less than one pixel. Horizontal/vertical lines are impossible to draw. Inclined lines might be visible, when drawing them aliasing will change adjusting pixels, so despite it's not really drawn you will see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research I found this thread: [Horizontal or vertical WPF Lines limited to 125,000 pixels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731593/horizontal-or-vertical-wpf-lines-limited-to-125-000-pixels)

So it seems that it is a bug in WPF if the line gets too long while being too thin...